# UICollectionViewController Footer/ Header not showing

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am implementing a one section `UICollectionViewController` where I would like to add a header & footer. 
I have read RayWenderlich tutorial to implement the logic and everything works fine EXCEPT my header & footer which are not showing up.

I checked "Section Header" & "Section Footer" in storyboard inspector, and added identifier for each `UICollectionReusableView` with "headerView" and "footerView".

I implemented the **`viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind`** method (see below code), but is not triggered (no breakpoints fired while debugging) while **`referenceSizeForFooterInSection`** and **`referenceSizeForHeaderInSection`** are . When app launch, I can't see header and footer background color, however I can see a space which should be header & footer.

Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

Here is an extract from my ViewController:

```
class VoteNextCityViewController : UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
fileprivate let sectionInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 50.0, left: 20.0, bottom: 50.0, right: 20.0)
fileprivate let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 2

private let cellID = "cellID"
var pendingCityArray: [City] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    fetchVotedCities()
}


override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! VoteNextCityCell
    let city = pendingCityArray[indexPath.row] //cannot not be nil, else numberOfItemsInSection would return 0
    cell.setupView(city: city)
    return cell
}

override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pendingCityArray.count
}



  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        //2
        let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRow + 1)
        let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
        let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow

        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem+50)
    }



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    return sectionInsets
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return sectionInsets.left
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {

    return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView?.frame.size.width)!, height: 50)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: (self.collectionView?.frame.size.width)!, height: 50)

}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    switch kind {
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter :
        let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "footerView", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

            return view
    case UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader:
            let view = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: "headerView", for: indexPath as IndexPath)
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

            return view

    default:
            assert(false, "Unexpected element kind")
    }
}
```

Comment: Try replacing `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {` with `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {`
I think `_` (underscore) is missing as per new syntax

Comment: @iRiziya OMG that's it! How to loose 3 hours of my life because of an underscore.
Thank you very much :)  Answer my question so that I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think only the `_` (underscore with a space) is missing as per new syntax.

So try replacing the function definition

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
```

with the below one

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
```